# this.props.history.push('/') is not working inside function

Tags: reactjs, axios

```
handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({error:{}})

if(this.isValid()){
    this.setState({isLoading : true})
    this.props.userSignUpRequest(this.state)
    .then(function(res){
            console.log(res +'ress')
            this.props.history.push('/'),  
            console.log("push")
                this.props.addFlashMsg({
                type: 'success',
                text: 'You signed up successfull. welcome '
            }),
            this.setState({isLoading: false})
        }
    )
    .catch(err=>{
  })}
```

}

i want to redirect according to the res that i am getting from server but when i write

```
.then(function(res){
    //....//
})
```

redirect dont work 
(for checking i log the response and it showed up but redirect is not working )

but when i use

```
.then(
   redirect and dispatch
)
```

both work
why this is happening?

Comment: error in console ? or you are getting undefined ?

Comment: no error but that function(redirect) is not working in first case

Comment: done this.props.context.history.push('/') and this.context.history.push('/') but both give same result

Comment: yp but i tried both way but it is not redirecting

Comment: try using arrow function `.then(res => {`

Comment: i want if server give me error msg then i will stay on page and ask to change username or if their is not any username previously in database then it will redirect them to /

Comment: yes and tried this.props.history.push("/") to but not success ful

Comment: @RobertFarley that dont work, i gave it a try

Comment: which version of react-router are you using ? and are you using redux ?

Comment: console in chrome show [object Object]ress so it is in the function for sure but not redirecting

Comment: react-router:2.4.0 and yes i am using redux 3.5.2

Comment: i got it this way of redirect do not work i have to use some new method of history library. but few moment ago it was working , and know without error it is misbehaving or may b my mistake . anyway thanku champions. thanku for your time